# Python não é tão "inteligente" para operações redundantes

Tags: python, python-3.x, desempenho, cache, otimização

Ao contrário de muitos casos em c++, o Python aparentemente não é tão inteligente para otimizar operações redundantes, mesmo entre constantes.

Eu fiz um benchmark simples para testar `math.cos` dentro e fora de um loop.

Neste primeiro caso, eu faço Python calcular cos(3) **10 milhões de vezes**:

```
from datetime import *
from math import *

ini = datetime.now()
for a in range(10000000):
    x = cos(0) 
fim = datetime.now()
print(fim - ini)
```

O resultado é `0:00:01.360958`.

Agora, apenas substituindo `x = cos(0)` por `x = 1` (ou apenas colocando `cos(0)` em uma variável fora do loop), o tempo fica **3 vezes mais rápido**: `0:00:00.429995`

Ora, se a operação `cos(0)` sempre gera uma constante (1), por que o Python não otimiza a execução com um cache, evitando assim a repetição da mesma operação `cos` constantemente?

Uma das filosofias do Python é facilitar a vida do programador. Mas neste caso o que está acontecendo é exatamente o oposto.

Comment: Na verdade, o Python sempre busca ser simples para o desenvolvedor resolver o problema, a performance nunca foi o foco. Se você precisa de algo mais rápido, cogite mudar a linguagem.  Perceba que mesmo chamando uma função com retorno constante o tempo de execução será praticamente o mesmo. É o tempo que o Python leva para resolver 10.000.000 de chamadas. Não tem relação direta com o cálculo do cosseno.

Comment: Para deixar claro, embora eu tenha comentado que a pergunta partiu de uma premissa errada, julgo ser uma pergunta perfeitamente dentro dos padrões do site e muito bem-vinda, pois essa provavelmente é a dúvida de várias outras pessoas. Com isso, não concordo com os votos negativos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Tornar a vida do programador mais fácil" não é exatamente uma coisa objetiva. Apesar disso, é o que a linguagem faz sim - mas "tornar a vida do programador mais fácil" não é sempre e em todos os casos "rodar todo o código existente da forma mais otimizada possível".

Inclusive, é sabido, e dito em quase todo material introdutório de Python que na verdade, ao usar Python, você está sim fazendo um trade de performance por facilidade de escrever o código.

E essa diferença de performance está ligada ao mesmo motivo principal dele não tentar curto-circuitar a chamada ao `cos`: Python é uma linguagem dinâmica - o que significa que as coisas são definidas em tempo de execução.

Esse exemplo que você passou não fica tão ruim. Na máquina virtual Python ele executa os opcodes 10_000_000 para o trecho do for, e mais a chamada a `cos` e retorno do valor explicitamente. Só que isso  isso cabe no cache L1 do processador - se o `cos` fosse uma função que, mesmo determinística, usasse mais memória do que cabe no L1, esse tempo seria muito, muito pior.

O principal motivo é que ao fazer a chamada a `cos`, a linguagem *não tem* como saber que a função `cos` na passada 1 milhão e 2 do laço é a mesma que estava lá na passada 1 milhão e 1.

Perceba que é possível que seu código seja assim:

```
from datetime import *
from math import *
import random

ini = datetime.now()
for a in range(10000000):
    x = cos(0) 
    if random.randint(0, 1_000_000) == 0:
          cos = sin
```

E pronto, em algum ponto, a função chamada passa a ser outra - como é tudo checado em tempo de execução, a linguagem simplesmente vai sempre chamar a função correta na linha `x = cos(0)`. Código desse tipo não é comum, mas mesmo assim, é da premissa da linguagem que esse tipo de código *tem* que funcionar.

Já acompanhei muitas discussões por e-mail entre os desenvolvedores de Python, de casos de otimizações que não podem ser implementadas no cPython - a implementação de referência da linguagem - por conta de não poderem passar por cima de uma possível alteração nos objetos entre duas etapas da execução. E estou falando de otimizações bem menos ingênuas do que essa que você pressupôs que deveria existir, com a sua pergunta.

Voltando a essa otimização específica, em C, C++ (e outras linguagens estáticas) é possível mudar a função chamada por um nome, mas isso não é comum, e vai envolver uma sintaxe diferente - tipo, chamar a função no endereço apontado pelo ponteiro de função `tal`. Daí é bem mais simples otimizar - mas mesmo em C, acho que isso não seria otimizado por padrão - por que o compilador não pode simplesmente *supor* que a função chamada é determinística (isso é, sempre vai retornar o mesmo valor para o mesmo valor de entrada).

Alias, no caso do `cos` em C, a única forma que o compilador "sabe" que pode trocar `cos(0)` por uma constante, é por que isso está marcado explicitamente, em algum ponto - ou no compilador, ou eco-sistema da biblioteca do sistema que culmina no arquivo `math.h`. Em Python, `cos`, `sin` e outras funções do tipo não são usadas o bastante [*] para terem esse status especial, mas o compilador faz sim otimizações parecidas para expressões estáticas colocadas no código - se você, numa linha de Python escreve `a = 2 ** 64` - o valor de 2 elevado a 64 é calculado em tempo de compilação, e essa linha vai carregar uma constante que é inserida no arquivo `.pyc` pré compilado. Meu teste aqui com C fez o mesmo para a saída da função `cos`.

Qualquer compilador que fizesse isso pra uma função arbitrária estaria tornando a linguagem inviável de ser usada na prática (vamos supor que seja o código para monitorar se a porta de um cofre está aberta, e chama a função do sensor - o cofre passa quase o tempo todo fechado, mas se *quando* ele for aberto o compilador tivesse assumido que ela o retorno da checagem seria "fechado", seria impossível ter esse programa)

Dito isso - o Python tem mecanismos para permitir que o programador possa explicitamente transformar uma função em algo com "cache" - e isso ele faz criando um novo objeto chamável, dinamicamente em tempo de execução, sem nenhuma regra especial - no caso, como apontado na resposta do Fernando Savio, a função `functools.lru_cache` pode ser usada para decorar uma função - e nesse caso o programador indica pra linguagem: "olha, pra essa função aqui, para os mesmos valores de entrada, pode usar sempre os mesmos valores de saída".

Agora, por fim, sim, se você quer esse tipo de otimização automática, e quer programar em Python, você ainda pode ter tudo - usando o [Pypy](http://pypy.org/features.html) - pypy é uma outra implementação de Python, que implementa otimização de compilação "*just in time*" (JIT) - aí sim, quando o *runtime* do pypy perceber que está num *loop* chamando a mesma função várias vezes, ele vai compilar todo o código dentro da função para código nativo, e isso vai ser executado muito mais rapidamente - e se em qualquer momento dentro do mesmo *loop*, a execução tomar um rumo diferente (tipo - o sensor detectou a porta do cofre aberta, ou o nome de variável `cos` agora aponta para outra função), ele reverte para execução normal.  E o motivo disso não ser o "padrão" na implementação do Python é simplesmente que não foi feito - otimização nesse nível de complexidade custa muito caro (em termos de homens hora), e mesmo com empresas como o Google, RedHat, IBM e Intel patrocinando ou dispostas a patrocinar alguns milhões de dólares em otimização do Python padrão, ainda não foi feito por falta de pessoas que conheçam o suficiente o Python e possam interagir com a comunidade, para faze-lo.  Mas sim, é possível que em vários anos, por conta de esforços desse tipo, tenhamos execução JIT também na implementação de referência.

[*] - então se você realmente for precisar da performance "*full*" da CPU para cálculos de `sin` e `cos`, e estiver programando em Python, a recomendação é que os seus números, com os quais você vai fazer as contas, estejam encapsulados em objetos especiais que fazem esse tipo de operação usando código nativo - por exemplo, a biblioteca NumPy, ou alguma biblioteca de OpenGL ou gráficos 3d, se o uso for para renderização de imagens, por exemplo.  `cos` nativo em Python tem que "embrulhar"  a resposta do código de máquina que calcula `cos` num objeto `float` - que tem todo o dinamismo que o Python precisa - essa operação é centenas de vezes mais custosa do que simplesmente armazenar na memória o numero de 8 bytes em ponto flutuante resultante da operação nativa.

Answer (score 6):

> Uma das filosofias do Python é facilitar a vida do programador

Está respondido. Isto é o oposto do que está preocupado. Talvez seja questão de interpretação do texto. Pelo menos eu não consigo imaginar como a falta de uma otimização seja um dificultador para o programador. Eu até entendo o desejo, mas isto não bate com a filosofia de Python. Cada um pode tentar interpretar o texto como quiser, mas a maioria das pessoas sabem que facilidade e otimização são coisas diferentes.

Quem quer performance, eficiência, abstração de custo zero, essas coisas é C++. C, Rust também, claro. Python nunca teve essas coisas como base para decidir nada do que fazer. Se a performance é o desejado escolha outra linguagem. Olha que facilidade.

Porém, você fez o teste no C++? E fez corretamente? testar é complicado. Eu não garanto que ele seja otimizado lá. É possível, e até provável, mas sem testar eu não garanto. E se é para otimizar mesmo isto deveria ser custo *near zero* porque todo o laço é inútil e basta fazer `x = 1` e mais nada, mata todo o *loop*, ou nem isso porque depois a variável nem é usada. Na verdade este código nem faz sentido. Inclusive a forma de medir também não é das mais adequadas.

Mas no final é uma questão de ninguém ter decidido fazer a otimização. Talvez porque poderia deixar a compilação mais lenta, ou por outro motivo. Pode ser que alguém ainda o faça, pode ser que você abra um *issue* e alguém faça, pode ser que você queria fazer e entregar para *review* da comunidade e a melhoria seja aplicada.

Answer (score 2):

As [filosofias do Python](https://zen-of-python.info) são 19, e nenhuma delas diz que é para facilitar a vida do programador.

Uma delas diz:

> Explícito é melhor do que implícito.

Dito isso, você como programador capaz de notar que o interpretador não faz **cache dos últimos resultados** de um cosseno, poderia utilizar o *decorator* [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) do módulo `functools` que serve justamente para isso, pois LRU significa *Last Recent Used*, que é justamente o que você quer que ele faça. Voltando novamente para o mantra:

> Explícito é melhor do que implícito.

Comment: Na verdade, "facilitar a vida do programador" não tem nada a ver com o não-problema que foi colocado.

Comment: Desculpa @jsbueno não entendi tua colocação.

Comment: é que "ser mais fácil pra programadores" é bastante subjetivo - mas não remete de forma nenhuma a 'adivinhar coisas pra ser o mais rápido possível'. Sua resposta está legal, mas trata essa colocação da pergunta como se fosse verdadeira. 
Por que, na verdade, as frases do zen of Python são meio anedóticas - é claro que uma das premissas da linguagem é tornar as coisas mais fáceis para programadores. Só que "inventar caches instantaneos só por que sim" não tem relação com isso.

Comment: Pois é, eu fiquei pensando também se não fui grosseiro... No fim não sei se a resposta acrescenta alguma coisa à comunidade fora falar de lru_cache.

Comment: Na verdade, essa pergunta demandaria mesmo uma consideração sobre a natureza da linguagem, que é dinâmica, e por isso não faz cache de nada - e depois, passar por cpython ser a implementação de referencia, e ai sim, apontar que o pypy tem JIT e faz o que ele está querendo.

Comment: Verdade... Vou apagar a resposta visto que não ajuda.

Comment: ela nao está cobrindo tudo oq ue tem que cobrir, mas ajuda sim - traz um dos argumentos de por que essa dúvida não é muito pertinente.
Uma reposta completa e compreensiva a essa pergunta seria quase um livro - então, se cada um que tocar aqui colocar um ou dois argumentos, todo mundo contribuiu.